# OpenGl - I can't draw square with glDrawArrays

Tags: opengl

I'm totally new in OpenGl programming. I'm working on example code which draws triangle. I managed to change it shape, but now I'm trying to get square. But with many attempts and digging google still getting only triangle displayed.

This is the part of the code :

```
glGenVertexArrays(VAO_cnt, VAOs);
glGenBuffers(VBO_cnt, VBOs);
float vtab[12]; 
vtab[0] = -0.5f; vtab[1] = -0.5f; vtab[2] = 0.0f;
vtab[3] = 0.5f; vtab[4] = 0.5f; vtab[5] = 0.0f;
vtab[6] = 0.5f; vtab[7] = -0.5f; vtab[8] = 0.0f;

vtab[9] = -0.5f; vtab[10] = 0.5f; vtab[11] = 0.0f;

glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOs[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vtab), vtab, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindVertexArray(VAOs[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 3);
```

Can anyone guide me how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 3);
```

is telling OpenGL to draw 3 points from your array. Try changing it to:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
```